# SonarScanner for .NET fails in GitHub Actions (.NET 5)

Tags: sonarqube, github-actions, sonarcloud

I'm trying to use SonarCloud in my GitHub Actions builds to analyze my code and to produce code coverage for my unit tests. I'm working on a .NET 5 solution in Visual Studio 2019.

At first, I was trying the SonarCloud GitHub action (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action), but the log told me to use the SonarScanner for .NET.
I've setup my workflow file following the documentation: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/.
I'm using the dotnet-sonarscanner global tool in the workflow.

The workflow looks like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  BuildLinux:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout Github Action'
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
          fetch-depth: 0
        
      - name: Setup dotnet
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}
     
      - name: Install Sonar global tool
        run: dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner

      - name: Begin Sonar scan
        run: dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"MySonarProject" /d:sonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and run unit tests
        run: |
          cd src
          dotnet restore "MySolution.sln"
          cd MyAPI
          dotnet build --no-restore
          cd -
          cd MyApiUnitTests
          dotnet build --no-restore
          dotnet test --no-build --no-restore --verbosity normal -p:CollectCoverage=true -p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover
          
      - name: End Sonar scan
        run: dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

When I run this build, I get the following error on the 'Begin Sonar scan' step. The installation of the global tool has succeeded.

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.2.1
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
05:54:44.604  Updating build integration targets...
05:54:44.688  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version': Connection refused (localhost:9000)
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader.Download(String url, Boolean logPermissionDenied)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<<DownloadServerVersion>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.DoLogExceptions[T](Func`1 op, String url)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.DownloadServerVersion()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetServerVersion()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.WarnIfSonarQubeVersionIsDeprecated()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs localSettings)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.PreProcess()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.Execute()
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

The build runs on ubuntu-latest, I also tried windows-latest. Same result.

How can I solve this issue? Can I use the Sonar scanner like this in GitHub Actions in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The log shows that it tries to connect to local instance of SonarQube, not SonarCloud. You would need to configure additional parameters to connect to SonarCloud: `/d:sonar.host.url=https://sonarcloud.io` and `/o:<your organization>`. See [SonarCloud version of task documentation](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) and SonarCloud [required parameters](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/analysis-parameters/#mandatory-parameters).